# How do I stretch a Xamarin GridLayout's contents to fill the screen?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using a `GridLayout` in Xamarin to create a Calculator app and am having trouble getting it to fill the screen. One possible solution I found was to use a `LinearLayout` for each row of the controls. The problem with this is that my `=` button spans two rows and I wasn't able to use it. I have also tried changing the `GridLayout`'s `layout_width` and `layout_height` with no luck. What other options do I have? Here's my code and some screenshots:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:text="0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:id="@+id/resultView" />
        <Button
            android:text="Del"
            android:id="@+id/button1" />
        <Button
            android:text="C"
            android:id="@+id/button1" />
        ... <!-- Buttons continue -->
        <Button
            android:text="3"
            android:id="@+id/button1" />
        <Button
            android:text="="
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:id="@+id/button1" />
        <Button
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:id="@+id/button1" />
        <Button
            android:text="."
            android:id="@+id/button1" />
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

What I have:

[image: Xamarin Calculator Layout]

What I want:

[image]

Edit: I know each button has the same `id`, but I'm only concerned with getting the layout right at the moment.

Comment: Have you tried with `android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"` for your grid layout?

Comment: @MilenPavlov I tried that, but it pushed all controls to the bottom left and stretched the `=` button to fill the rest of the space. I need it to stretch all controls evenly.

Comment: Ok, you can have multiple linear layouts in your Grid layout (or just use Linear Layout insead - this is what I've used) and set the layout weight for each one of them (just make sure that linear layouts are match_parent) see: http://www.chess-ix.com/blog/the-use-of-layout_weight-with-android-layouts/

Comment: @MilenPavlov With this approach, is it possible to retain my original design with the equals button spanning multiple rows? I don't see how it's possible with `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Yes, of course you just have to play a bit with the layouts - for example starting with Horizontal linear layout and two linear layouts as a children with layout weights 1 and 3...

Comment: If you're targeting API 21 and higher, I think that weight was added to GridLayout so it should be possible to define the weight property on the cells and make it space them evenly without the LinearLayout.  I haven't tried anything like that though.